# Fuzzy search for group of word / multiple terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to make fuzzy searches on group of words (and not only single terms).

My database table have many strings, containing 1 or more words, and I need to find the best fit for a searched group of words.

### E.G:

I search ***"pommes de terre"***, it should give ***"pomme de terre"***, and with inferior score, ***"pomme"***, ***"terre"***, or any possible matching term.

For single terms, it works perfectly, and corrects typoes, and heavy mistakes.
But if I search for many terms, single terms have better scores than exact matches, and group of words:

#### Search: "pomme de terre"

- poire, score:2.3862941
- pomme, score:2.2527628
- **pomme de terre**, score:1.1263814 ***<- Not high enough***

### Question

> **Is there a solution which gives a better score the more terms matches ?** (the more fuzzy terms matches, the more score is high)

### SETTINGS

Search Query:

```
{query: 
    {fuzzy_like_this: 
        { like_text: 'pomme de terre'}
    }
}
```

Settings:

```
:analysis => {
    :analyzer => {
        :folding => {
            :tokenizer => "icu_tokenizer",
            :filter => [ "icu_folding"]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner, using elasticsearch-rails. I tried to use suggest queries, but they are not usable with rails gem.

I have to precise that this search is a big part of my project...

Comment: do you have find a way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. Here's how I fixed it using Java-8 and ES-1.7.

```
QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("pommes de terre","name")
.fuzziness(3)
.minimumShouldMatch("90%")
.type(Type.MOST_FIELDS);
```

**Note**: minimumShouldMatch is what does the trick here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and came to the conclusion that fuzzy query is not what I needed.
Fuzzy queries are term-level queries. I got much better results with a match query, which you can apply fuzziness on thanks to the `fuzziness` param.